# How to install changed source file using puppet?

Tags: puppet

I changed a source file in for one of my puppet modules, but an older version is already installed. How do I re-apply puppet so that it installs the new package?

Answer (score 0):

A puppet run would make sure that the new file is present.
If you want to remove the older version, you can use `ensure => absent`